# What is the correct syntax for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to fade in images on top of an existing image when I mouse over them, without re-writing the same function for each image.

Currently I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.image').mouseenter(function() {  //fade in hover image
            $(this.getAttribute("name")).fadeIn(500);
        });                         
        $('.hoverimage').mouseout(function() { //fade out hover image
            $(this).fadeOut(500);
        });

    });

</script>

...
...

<!--base images-->
<img src="image1.png" class="image" name="hoverimage1">
<img src="image2.png" class="image" name="hoverimage2">
<img src="image3.png" class="image" name="hoverimage3">

<!--image to appear when hovering over-->
<img src="image1_glow.png" class="hoverimage" id="hoverimage1">
<img src="image2_glow.png" class="hoverimage" id="hoverimage2">
<img src="image3_glow.png" class="hoverimage" id="hoverimage3">
```

Assume that CSS is already there so that the hover image is placed on top of the base image. What my code tries to do is:

- When mouse enters div of "image1.png", it will get the name attribute "hoverimage1"
- Then it fades in an element with the ID "hoverimage1" by essentially executing $('#hoverimage1").fadeIn(500);

But the problem is the name attribute doesn't have "#", and I don't want to write "name="#hoverimage1" cause that's confusing for IDs. Right now my function executes $('hoverimage1").fadeIn(500); which is not correct syntax.

Can someone help me with this? Is it possible to append a "#" to the "$(this.getAttribute())" or something?

Comment: +1 for not wasting time creating a jQuery object just to get an attribute.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prepend a `#`, then you can just concatenate the strings:

```
$('#' + this.name)
```

But I'd use the element index for this, if possible:

```
    $('.image').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.other_images').eq($(this).index()).stop().fadeIn(500);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.other_images').eq($(this).index()).stop().fadeOut(500);
    });
```

That way, you don't even need to write the other image's `id` in the `name` attribute of the parent image.

Comment: I don't really follow the logic of your code. How exactly does `$('.other_images').eq($(this).index())` work? I don't see how it can tell which hover image to fade in.

Comment: @Windbrand: `.eq(2)` selects the third image that matches the selector. `.index()` gets the index of the current element in the selector, so basically when you click on the first image in that set of elements, the first image in the other set of elements is animated.

Answer (score 2):

Since the attribute is `hoverimage1`, the script is literally looking for a `<hoverimage1>` element. You need to concatenate a `#` to the beginning: `$("#"+this.getAttribute("name"))`